# Where is the option to convert from a java project to a plug-in project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde, target-platform

I cannot find it. Under PDE tools (after right clicking on project), I only have Open Manifest, Organize Manifests, Externalize Strings, Internationalize, API Tools Setup, Update Classpath, and Open Dependencies.

Do I need a specific update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the project, the converter option is in the "Configure" menu. If your project is already a plug-in project this option will be hidden.

If you can see the "PDE tools" menu then your project is probably already converted. You can check it in project properties. It will have a "Plug-in Developement" page if the project is a plugin project. Besides that the "Builders" page will have the plug-in builders configured.